# Not getting nested values from req.query in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node. I am using monogdb and document looks like this:

```
{
    "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -77.376204,
                    38.492158
            ],
            "formattedAddress": "200 Olympic Dr, Stafford, VA 22554-7763, US",
            "street": "200 Olympic Dr",
            "city": "Stafford",
            "state": "VA",
            "zipcode": "22554-7763",
            "country": "US"
 }
```

I want to filter data using req.query. I want to get data according to city.

For example: To get all jobs in london city, I typed below url.

https://localhost:3000/jobs?location.city=London

But there is no data in req.query.

Node Code:
I am just finding it in database by writing following line:

```
Job.find(req.query)
```

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: please add your nodejs code as well here so we can help you.

Comment: Now check the code.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using `[express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)` right? If yes, please can you share the routing code for this particular endpoint?